# Possible ways to make text graphics to be indexed by Google?

Tags: html, css

Because of my native language good for web designing fonts are not available.
I would like to use some special fonts only in the header of my page and two possible solutions is to use cufon or images with text on them. I prefer the second solution, but for also I am asking this for general knowledge.

My question is, can I get these text graphics indexed by Google somehow? for example this below

```
<img src="welcome.png"></img><img src="to.png"></img><img src="my.png"></img>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `img`'s `alt` attribute, that's what it was made for.

```
<img src="welcome.png" alt="welcome"/>
<img src="to.png" alt="to"/>
<img src="my.png" alt="my"/>
```

Take a look at the [w3.org article](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/img#Text_that_has_been_rendered_to_a_graphic_for_typographical_effect) about this.